# Loading pitures as different pages to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to make an app with sliding between a few pictures (like in gallery). I am using ViewPager for this task. I know how to add activities to ViewPager for sliding between them. But if there is a method that allows to take all pictures from a directory and add them to ViewPager without creating activity for each picture manually?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should implement your custom PagerAdapter which will populate your ViewPager with Fragments (!) containing your images

Comment: And try to Google this: "android gallery viewpager". The first two result will be helpful for you

Comment: A view pager only holds views... I dont think it holds activities.. please do a crosscheck krosh. And if your really know how to add activities to view pager .. Do tell us..

Comment: @coelho Thank you. I didn't think to make such request. I've found a few examples

Comment: @amalBit Thank you for your correction. I'm a little weak in terminology